# script file has to change property names in aws s3

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have more than `1000` files in `aws s3` bucket in different `folders`, all the files are `json` files only, these `json` files have `30 properties`, now I have to change the name of 2 properties (Ex: `code` to `httpCode` and `time` to `responseTime`). Can we write a `script` file which can change these property names in all files

Answer (score 1):

Note: You should run this command without `-i` switch in `sed` command just to verify that you are getting desired results. `-i` will make changes in the file. If you are getting desired results then only put `-i` switch.

```
// Get the files from s3 bucket
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket .
find . -iname "*.json" -type f -exec sed -i 's/code/httpCode/g;s/time/responseTime/g' {} \;
// sync the files with s3 from current local directory
aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket
```

ps: this is untested.